# Is there a non periodic sequence of 1 and 0 such that its power series can be analytically continued outside of the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, p-adic-number-theory

This is something i came across during my own research, i went around and asked quite a few people ( most of them teaching math at college ) and none did manage do give me a definite answer. Disclaimer: i post this from phone, so don't mind me writing formulas using only standard phone keyboard i currently work with, i will try my best to make it readable, + gonna be a bit longer post.

The question is following:

Is there a function f: $\mathbb{N} \to \{0, 1\}$ that satisfies the following:

- there is no ordered pair $(n, t)$ such that for each natural number $a$,

  $$a>n \implies f(a)=f(a+t)$$

  aka the tail of $f$ is not periodic.
- Let $g(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{k=\infty} f(k) z^k$, where $|z|<1$ aka $g$ is defined inside the unit circle of the complex plane excluding the circle boundary. $g(z)$ can be analytically continued to outside the unit circle.

What i know so far is that there are examples of functions that satisfy the first property and doesn't satisfy the second ; the ones i know of are $f(x)=1$ if $x=2^k, k$ natural, and $0$ otherwise, and one more with $k!$ instead of $2^k$.

Of course, it is easily shown that if the function doesn't satisfy the first property, it must satisfy the other one.

This is a simplified version of the problem where instead of $\{0, 1\}$, the codomain of $f$ is $\{0, 1, ... n\}$ for some fixed $n$.

This more general problem has came from an attempt to identify ( as many as possible ) the members of p-adic number system, where $p = n$ with complex values such that the set of numbers that can be identified in this way together with p-adic operations on them is isomorphic with the subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that is made from elements they are identified with.

So that was a little bit of background. The main purpose of it was to suggest a possible candidate for $f$ in a more general version of the problem. Let $n=7$, and $x$ be one of the solutions of the equation $x^2=2$ in $\mathbb{Q}_7$, obviously there are 2 solutions opposite to each other ( $x_1+x_2 = 0$ ), $f(k)$ is then the $k$-th digit in the representation of x in $\mathbb{Q}_7$.

What i believe is that both solutions generate us a function that would satisfy both properties and that the values of analytic continuations of respective $g_1(z)$ and $g_2(z)$ at $z=7$ will be equal to $\sqrt{2}$ and $- \sqrt{2}$ respectively.

Ty for reading until the end and thank you for any help on the topic, i am looking forward to read the answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are interested in [lacunary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function).  Let us label your function, 
$$  g(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k) z^k  \text{.} $$

It is an old result that if the coefficients of the series $g$ come from a finite set, and the sequence of coefficients in $g$ are not eventually periodic, then the series cannot be continued outside of the unit disk.    From Einar Hille's "Analytic Function Theory, vol. 2", [p. 87](https://books.google.com/books?id=rY8__WxS2zsC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=aperiodic+power+series+that+are+not+lacunary&source=bl&ots=-f7U1qxBQL&sig=z_sl2R3FaFTpbqOpC63YgBuVRis&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5odD5p4fWAhUEwYMKHQJiAO8Q6AEIPDAE#v=onepage&q=aperiodic%20power%20series%20that%20are%20not%20lacunary&f=false)

> Another case is that in which the coefficients have only a finite number of distinct values.  If these values do not ultimately form a periodic sequence, the series is noncontinuable [outside the unit disk].

Bell et al. (Bell, Jason P., Nils Bruin, and Michael Coons, "Transcendence of Generating Functions Whose Coefficients are Multiplicative", https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.2221.pdf ) give a start into the literature with their Theorem 1.2:

> **Theorem 1.2** (Carlson [10])**.**  A series $F(z) = \sum_{n \geq 1} f(n) z^n \in \mathbb{Z}[[z]]$ that converges inside the unit disk is either rational or it admits the unit circle as a natural boundary.

Of course, if it is rational, it is eventually periodic.